# FBProfilePictureView not showing profile photo

Tags: ios, objective-c

I have the following method as in Facebook's tutorial.

However, the profile photo does not show up.

I can see the user.name in the userNameLabel, and looking at the log the self.userProfilePictureView.profileIDis set properly.

```
- (void)populateUserInfo{
    AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];
    [appDelegate requestUserData:^(id sender, id<FBGraphUser> user) {
        self.userNameLabel.text = user.name;
        self.userProfilePictureView.profileID = [user objectForKey:@"id"];
        NSLog(@"%@", self.userProfilePictureView.profileID);
    }];
}
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12437046/get-facebook-user-profile-data-after-getting-access-token-in-ios-5    pls refer this hope this will helpfully u ..

Answer (score 0):

Did you add a `[FBProfilePictureView class]` in the first line of `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` in the AppDelegate?